# Configure a usb wireless adapter when hotplugged

Tags: networking, wifi, usb, access-point

I have a pc connected to the internet on eth0 and I have a usb wifi dongle: I succeeded to configure it as a hotspot to which I can connect from my mobile devices so that I can share the pc internet connection.

For this, I wrote two scripts: `ap-on` to activate the AP and `ap-off` to deactivate it and they work fine. (I will include them at the end of the message, for reference).

What I would like is that they get automatically triggered when I insert the usb key. So I wrote a udev rule which looks like

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:13:46:78:c5:4e", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan2", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/ap-on > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

What happens is that `ap-on` is started upon hotplug but the device wlan2 doesn't get configured properly: with `ifconfig` I get

```
wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 00:13:46:78:c5:4e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:0 (0.0 B)
```

whereas when I start it manually I get

```
mon.wlan2 Link encap:UNSPEC  IndirizzoHW 00-13-46-78-C5-4E-3A-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:0 (0.0 B)

wlan2     Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW 00:13:46:78:c5:4e  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.23.1  Bcast:192.168.23.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::213:46ff:fe78:c54e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:43 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:0 (0.0 B)  Byte TX:7751 (7.7 KB)
```

Why does this happens?

Second question: how should I change the rule to have `ap-off` launched when I remove the usb key?

Here is `ap-on`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Config files  
hotspotconfig="/etc/hostapd/my-ap-hotspot.conf"
dhcpdconfig="/etc/dhcp/my-dhcpd-hotspot.conf"

# Network interface to the internet
NETnic=eth0
# Wireless network interface for the access point
APnic=wlan2
# Write the hostapd config file
cat <<EOF | tee "$hotspotconfig" > /dev/null 2>&1
interface=$APnic
driver=nl80211
ssid=hotspot-$APnic
hw_mode=g
channel=2
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=bhu87ygv
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
EOF
# Write the dhcpd config file
cat <<EOF | tee "$dhcpdconfig" > /dev/null 2>&1
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 864000;

subnet 192.168.23.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.23.20 192.168.23.25;
  option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
  option routers 192.168.23.1;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.23.255;
}
EOF

#set IP address
ifconfig $APnic 192.168.23.1
## start hostapd
hostapd -d $hotspotconfig > /var/log/hostapd.log &
sleep 2

# launch dhcpd daemon
dhcpd -cf $dhcpdconfig $APnic 
sleep 2

# set kernel variable(s)
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding

# create iptables rules
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.23.0/24 -o $NETnic -j MASQUERADE

exit 0
```

and here is `ap-off`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Config files  
hotspotconfig="/etc/hostapd/my-ap-hotspot.conf"
dhcpdconfig="/etc/dhcp/my-dhcpd-hotspot.conf"

# Network interface to the internet
NETnic=eth0
# Wireless network interface for the access point
APnic=wlan2

# stop hostapd and dhcpd
killall  hostapd 
killall  dhcpd

# remove iptables rules
iptables -t nat -F 

# set kernel variable(s)
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/forwarding

# unconfig wifi nic
ifconfig $APnic down

# remove config files
rm -f $hotspotconfig
rm -f $dhcpdconfig

exit 0
```

Comment: You're currently redirecting the output of the script in the udev rule to `/dev/null`.  Why not trying to redirect it to a file instead? (if it will work)

Comment: @garethTheRed I tried to redirect it to a file, changing RUN to `RUN+="/usr/local/bin/ap-on > /tmp/ap.log 2>&1"` but the log file is not even created... ?!?

Comment: So how do you know that `ap-on` has actually ran? There is no log and no changes to the network config.  Maybe the issue is that the script is fine, but `udev` isn't running it.

Comment: To check if it actually ran, I added something like `touch /tmp/check` in it, in different places, and it runs. I guess that udev takes care of the output.

Comment: Anyway, you gave me a hint: I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and I discovered that the problem (I think) is that networkmanager runs after my script and deregister the address 192.168.23.1! I guess that when starting it manually I am not so quick as to beat networkmanager... All in all, I addedd `iface wlan2 inet manual` in `/etc/network/interface` and now it works. It is a workaround, not an actual solution, but it works.

Comment: And what about launching a script when I remove the adapter?

Comment: Maybe add `iface eth0 inet manual` to `/etc/network/interfaces` (Debian/Ubuntu) or add `NM_CONTROLLED='no'` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (RedHat variants).

Comment: Similar rule, with `ACTION="remove"`.